# Блоки неправильно отображаются

Tags: html, css

Проблема в том, что 3 блока находятся на разных уровнях:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


<div class="features">
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="title title-text">Заголовок</div>
        <div class="content">Бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла</div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="title title-text">Заголовок</div>
        <div class="content">Бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла</div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="title title-text">Заголовок</div>
        <div class="content">Бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла</div>
    </div>

</div>

<style type="text/css">
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .features {
        width: 100%;

        position: absolute;

        top: 50%;
    }
    .feature {
        display: inline-block;

        width: 33%;
        height: 50vh;
    }
    .feature .title {
        position: relative;
        left: 45%;

        width: 50px;


        text-align: center;

        transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    }
    .feature .content {
        width: 50%;
        position: relative;

        left: 50%;
        top: 4%;

        transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    }
</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Но, если, кол-во символов в блоке .feature .content одинаковы, то всё отображается корректно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно прописать `vertical-align: top;` для `feature`, что бы контент выравнивался по верхней линии.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, помогло ;D

Answer (score 0):

У вас изначально не верный подход к верстке. Для выравнивание блоков уже давно пора использовать flex или grid

```css
.wrrap {
  height: 400px;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;  
}
.features {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.feature {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrrap">
<div class="features">
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="title">Заголовок</div>
        <div class="content">Бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла</div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="title">Заголовок</div>
        <div class="content">Бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла</div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="title">Заголовок</div>
        <div class="content">Бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла</div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```